# Can you decrypt RSA ciphertext given Decryption Oracle and public exponent only?

Tags: rsa, decryption-oracle

Linked is a website that has a capture the flag problem with RSA: https://konsolas-2022-04-24.herokuapp.com/

I know very little about RSA decrypting but I do want to try and solve it, but I'm not sure where to start. I found https://www.tausquared.net/src/pages/ctf/rsa.html which would be useful if I knew the public exponent, but unfortunately I don't.

Is it possible to decrypt the ciphertext, and if so, could you provide any hints on how to start? Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140813/discussion-on-question-by-jeremy-can-you-decrypt-rsa-ciphertext-given-decryption).